# SO Careers 2.0 - How do top answers work?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

In my Careers 2.0 profile I added some top answers. However, I can't see them in my public profile. In the FAQ and help I couldn't find anything about top answers. So why aren't my top answers showing up in my careers profile?

Comment: do you see answers in _edit profile_ and in _employer_ views?

Comment: in edit profile i can see it, but not in employer views

Comment: interesting. That looks like a bug; just checked my profile - my answers are displayed in all three views, edit/public/employer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because we're screwups :) Thanks for the report. This is fixed now.