# Top Answers not showing in public and only heading in edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

This seems quite similar to [SO Careers 2.0 - How do top answers work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136652/189763), but it says it has been fixed there so I believe it may be a different issue.

When I have added multiple answers to top answers on [my SO careers profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/employer/132374), I do not see them at all in the public view. I only see the headings in edit mode.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that Ryan. Thanks for the report. Your profile should be fixed now.

Comment: It is fixed. Thank you.